# Captured image can be saved to Images folder but cannot be saved to app folder

Tags: android, file, android-bitmap

I can save the captured image to Pictures folder however i cannot save it to app folder. I give permissions for camera and write permission dynamically. I write read write camera permission in manifests.xml. I checked permission at debug mode. There is no problem with permissions.

Camera activity starts and i take picture and click OK. Then in onActivityResult() i checked the image file's size.It's zero byte. Image file exists but zero length.

Here is how i retrieve image path :

```
public static File getImageFile(Context context, int food_id) {
    try {
        //File storageDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + IMAGES_DIRECTORY);    // not works !!!!!!!!!
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + IMAGES_DIRECTORY); // works
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File photoFile = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + food_id + ".jpg");

       /* if(!photoFile.exists())
            photoFile.createNewFile();*/

        return photoFile;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    hasPermissionCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(FoodDetailsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (hasPermissionCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) { 
            getErrorDialog(getString(R.string.permission_error_dialog_camera), FoodDetailsActivity.this, true).show();
        } else { 
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_CAMERA);
        }
    } else { // open camera
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)  // intent düzgün mü diye kontrol eder.
        {

            File photoFile = AppUtil.getImageFile(FoodDetailsActivity.this,food_id);  

            if (photoFile != null) {
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        } else {

        }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentx) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentx);
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File imageFile = AppUtil.getImageFile(this,food_id);
        try {
            mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());  // mImageBitmap is null here. imageFile exists.
            Log.d("eeffs","size : " + imageFile.length() + " - exists() : " + imageFile.exists()); exists return true. length is zero

            int widthBitmap = mImageBitmap.getWidth();  // exception here because bitmap is null
            ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cannot save it to app folder

I am going to guess that you mean:

```
File storageDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + IMAGES_DIRECTORY);    // not works !!!!!!!!!
```

Third party apps have no ability to write to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and you are invoking a third-party camera app via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

You can use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method to provide selective access to your app's portion of internal storage. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.12/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates the technique, where I also write to a location inside of `getFilesDir()`.

As a bonus, using `FileProvider` will allow you to get rid of that ugly `StrictMode` hack that you are using to try to get past the ban on `file` `Uri` schemes.

Comment: in your LegacyCompatFileProvider class, you imported com.commonsware.cwac.provider.LegacyCompatCursorWrapper and use this class. I cannot find this class in your repo. Can you please help?

Comment: @metis: That comes from [the `cwac-provider` library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which is included in the project as a dependency.